# Controlling text formatting, linebreaks, and colors of custom button with template

Tags: wpf, templates

I've been asked to build a relatively simple application launcher program (to replace an old DOS-based menu system).  I've built the application in WPF and created a custom class derived from Button called "ApplicationLauncherButton".

I wanted all of the buttons to have the same "look-and-feel", so I decided they would all be styled the same.  As such, I decided to replace the control template with one that I would create.  To keep my main window XAML as clean as possible, I created a separate resource dictionary file to hold the template and referenced it in the app.xaml.

This worked reasonably well.  However, some of the text on the buttons is very long and I wanted to control where linebreaks would occur.  This was accomplished relatively easily by wrapping the button text in a TextBlock and inserting  tags where I wanted them.  Unfortunately, this had a side effect:  the text color change I wanted to occur on a mouse-over event was no longer being applied.  When the button text is NOT wrapped in a TextBlock, the mouse-over formatting works as desired, but I lose the ability to control where the linebreaks occur.

I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure out how to get it to work, but haven't had any luck.  I've only been working with WPF for a couple of weeks, so there may be a much easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WPF1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\Default\Button.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPF1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Application Launcher" Height="787" Width="728" 
        Background="{StaticResource Default.DarkGreenBrush}" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <GroupBox Header="Design Programs" Margin="5" Foreground="White" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold">
            <WrapPanel>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton 
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\DesignerApp1.exe"
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                        Designer Application 1
                    </TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\DesignerApp2.exe"
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Designer<LineBreak/>
                        Application 2
                    </TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\DesignerApp3.exe"
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Designer<LineBreak/>
                        Application 3
                    </TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\DesignerApp4.exe                    
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Designer<LineBreak/>
                        Application 4
                    </TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\DesignerApp5.exe                    
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Designer<LineBreak/>
                        Application 5
                    </TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
            </WrapPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Utility Programs" Margin="5" Foreground="White" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold">
            <WrapPanel>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\UtilityApp1.exe                    
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Utility<LineBreak/>
                        Application 1</TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\UtilityApp2.exe                    
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Utility<LineBreak/>
                        Application 2</TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\UtilityApp3.exe                    
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Utility<LineBreak/>
                        Application 3</TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\UtilityApp4.exe                    
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Utility<LineBreak/>
                        Application 4</TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
                <local:ApplicationLauncherButton
                    ApplicationUncPath="\\server\applications\UtilityApp5.exe                    
                    Click="ApplicationLauncherButton_Click">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Utility<LineBreak/>
                        Application 5</TextBlock>
                </local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
            </WrapPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Button.xaml (in the \Themes\Default folder of the project)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF1">

    <!-- Colors -->
    <Color x:Key="Default.LightGreen">#509248</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Default.DarkGreen">#014419</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Static.Background.Color">#FFDDDDDD</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Static.Border.Color">#FF707070</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Static.Foreground.Color">#FFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background.Color">#90D288</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border.Color">#FF707070</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Foreground.Color">#EEEE00</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background.Color">#307228</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border.Color">#FF505050</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background.Color">#FFF4F4F4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border.Color">#FFADB2B5</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground.Color">#FF838383</Color>

    <!-- Brushes -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Default.LightGreenBrush" Color="{StaticResource Default.LightGreen}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Default.DarkGreenBrush" Color="{StaticResource Default.DarkGreen}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Default.LightGreen}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Foreground.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.Static.Foreground.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Foreground.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Foreground.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border.Color}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground.Color}"/>

    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" 
                                   Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ApplicationLauncherButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background.Brush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border.Brush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Foreground.Brush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="125"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="125"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="control" TargetType="{x:Type local:ApplicationLauncherButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Visibility="Visible"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background.Brush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border.Brush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"  TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Foreground.Brush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background.Brush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border.Brush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"  TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Foreground.Brush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background.Brush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border.Brush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground.Brush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

On a side note, part of the reason I've structured my window as I have is that I intend to move the application information to a data source, dynamically creating buttons and groups based upon the data.  This will allow me to add / remove applications without having to modify the Application Launcher code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not mix plain text and `Inline` elements as content of the `TextBlock`.
Use a `Run` to display the text. Then bind the `Run.Foreground` property to the `Button` (or the parent `TextBlock`). See example below.

Also your button's template is wrong. You should not wrap the `ContentPresenter` into a `TextBlock`, especially when you add another `TexBlock` as value for the `Button.Content`. This will give you a `TextBlock` nested into a `TextBlock`:

```xml
<TextBlock> x:Name="TextBlockFromTemplate">
  <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockToReplaceContentPresenter" />
</TextBlock>
```

Also bind the `ContentPresenter.HorizontalAlignment` to the templated parent's `HorizontalContentAlignment` (same for the `ContentPresenter.VerticalAlignment`). Don't set it explicitly as this would disconnect the `Button.HorizontalContentAlignment` from the template, making it useless.

You can use a `Style` that targets `Run`, and which you add to `ResourceDictionary` of the `Style` for the `ApplicationLauncherButton`, to avoid repeating code:

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ApplicationLauncherButton}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Run">
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}" />
    </Style>
  </Style.Resources>

  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate x:Name="control"
                       TargetType="{x:Type local:ApplicationLauncherButton}">
        <Border x:Name="border"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="Orange" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

### Example

```xml
<local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
  <TextBlock>
    <Run>Designer</Run>
    <LineBreak />
    <Run>Application 4</Run>
  </TextBlock>
</local:ApplicationLauncherButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, but It turns out, the answer I really needed was even more elementary.  In the Trigger for when "IsMouseOver" is "true", I simply needed to set the Foreground property to the desired color for the button, rather than specifying a control in the template.  So:

<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Foreground.Brush}"/>

rather than

<Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Foreground.Brush}"/>